# How to code a set of enum classes that all should support a public static method

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to write some Java code for a set of enum classes.

Each of the enums encapsulate some conceptually distinct data, so it doesn't make sense to combine them. The enums also map to values in a database, and so also share some common operations, both instance and static operations, related to loading data from the database.

I need to generalise the set of enum classes I have, such that I can pass any one of these enums into a different class which performs and caches of database lookups relating to each of the different enums.

Since the cache/lookup class will also depend on the public and static methods defined in each enum, how can I code my solution so that I can guarantee that any enum that can be passed into the class will have the required methods?

The normal approach would be to define an interface, but interfaces don't allow static methods.

Alternatively, you might use an abstract class to define the interface and some of the common implementation, but I don't believe that is possible with enums (I understand that enums must extend the Enum class and cannot be extended).

What are my options do I have that enable me to ensure all of my enums implement the methods I need?

Example enum:

```
public enum MyEnum{
    VALUE_ONE("my data");
    VALUE_TWO("some other data");

    /**
     * Used when mapping enums to database values - if that sounds odd, 
     * it is: it's legacy stuff
     *
     * set via private constructor
     */
    private String myValue; 
    //private constructor not shown

    public static MyEnum lookupEnumByString(String enumValue){
        //find the enum that corresponds to the supplied string
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the specific requirements you have, but **except for very specific cases** where the database values are **constant** and **small in numbers**, mapping Enums to database values tend to be an overkill that leads to increased complexity. With that said implementing an interface (or implementing a static method as in your example) would be just fine.

Comment: Yes, I agree +1. In our case this represents static data stored in the database so that it can be modified without altering the code. The enums are also used to define acceptable values for a public facing web interface, so we have found it's easiest to encapsulate the mapping from external data to our web service to our database using this set of enums

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*It's all quite complicated and there may be errors, but I hope you get the idea.*

```
// I'm not sure about the right type arguments here
public interface MyEnumInterface<E extends MyEnumInterface & Enum<E>> {
    public static boolean aUsefulNonStaticMethod();
    String getValue();
    MyEnumInfo<E> enumInfo();
}

/** contains some helper methods */
public class MyEnumInfo<E extends MyEnumInterface<E>> {
    private static <E extends MyEnumInterface<E>> MyEnumInfo(Class<E> enumClass) {...}
    // static factory method
    public static <E extends MyEnumInterface<E>> MyEnumInfo<E> infoForClass(Class<E> enumClass) {
        ... return a cached value
    }
    public static <E extends MyEnumInterface<E>> MyEnumInfo(E e) {
         return infoForClass(e.getClass());
    }
    // some helper methods replacing static methods of the enum class     
    E enumForValue(String value) {....}
}

public enum MyEnum implements MyEnumInterface<MyEnum> {
    VALUE_ONE("my data");
    VALUE_TWO("some other data");

    private String myValue; //set via private constructor
    //private constructor not shown

    public boolean aUsefulNonStaticMethod(){
        //do something useful
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return myValue;
    }

    // the ONLY static method in each class
    public static MyEnumInfo<E> staticEnumInfo() {
        return MyEnumInfo.infoForClass(MyEnumClass.class);
    }
    // the non-static version of the above (may be useful or not)
    public MyEnumInfo<E> enumInfo() {
        return MyEnumInfo.infoForClass(getClass());
    }
}
```

It's a bit strange, that you're using another String in addition to Enum.name(), do you need it?

Because of all enums extending Enum, you can't let them share any code. The best you can do is delegating it all to a helper static method in a utility class.

There's no way to force classes to implement a static method, which is understandable, since there's no way (except for reflection) to call them.

Comment: The enums map to values in the database, the string is part of the key in that mapping. The myEnum parameter is a typo on my part, it should take a string and return the corresponding enum. I'll correct the question

Comment: There's `Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` which may do what you need. Moreover, there's an implicitly declared `valueOf(String name)` in each enum.

Comment: Unfortunately, the database stores codes, not meaningful names, so using the database value as the enum name, which is what I believe you propose, wouldn't really be a good idea. That's why we stored the string alongside the enum constant

Comment: I see. Then there's probably no nice solution. Consider creating an `EnumInfo` class with one instance per your enum class and implementing the functionality you need. I'll extend my answer.

Comment: +1 Your updated answer is probably the closest solution to the question to date. The genericised helper class would encapsulate the static implementation and would be easily applied to any enum that extends the `MyEnumInterface`, whilst the interface provides the contract each enum must provide. I would include a non-static `enumInfo()` method in the interface to ensure each enum exposes the utility class and indirectly exposes the static methods I require

Comment: Just wanted to point out that your first sentence is redundant since I updated the question

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest I can think of.

You have a class containing your common functionality:

```
class Util{

    //common functionality
    public void doSomething(){

    }
}
```

Each Enum has has an instance of this class and can override its methods if necessary:

```
enum Enum1{
    FOO, 
    BAR;

    private Util util = new Util();

    public Util getUtil() {
        return util;
    }

}

enum Enum2{
    ALICE, 
    BOB;

    private Util util = new Util(){
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            //this one has overridden it
        };
    };

    public Util getUtil() {
        return util;
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
Enum2.ALICE.getUtil().doSomething();
```

Comment: Better to use an interface "`SomethingDoer`" with the method "`doSomething()`" and have the enums implement it. Then you can just call `ALICE.doSomething()`.

Comment: If you use an interface, you end up duplicating code in your enums. You can certainly make Util implement an interface if you like. You could have 5 enums and maybe want to override doSomething in only one of them.

Comment: In your example, your `doSomething()` methods do different things. There is nothing preventing several enum implementations from calling the same method if they like. Also, using an interface you can supply any enum to any method expecting a `SomethingDoer`. Besides, in your example you're duplicating more code, the definition of `Util` and the extra `getUtil()` method.

Comment: in such a case, you could parametrize instances of the interfaces (as handlers), passing the same "handler" to those enums that require the same behavior (a-la strategy pattern). It is rare (very rare) the case where class inheritance is the better choice over composition via interface inheritance. Composition trumps class inheritance most of the time.

Comment: +1 Yes, this probably represents the simplest solution, which is relevant since the majority of our dev team has a C# rather than Java background, so it will be easier to maintain

Answer (score 2):

** WARNING** the following is Java-pseudocode, and as such, will not compile.

So you want to attach logic to individual enums. This could possibly require some enums to share the same logic while having other enums with their own, specific logic. Also, you want to associate String keys that might not be the same as the Enum's name (what's typically returned by `Enum.name()`.

The following **java-based pseudocode** shows one way (one of the many) in which you could do that. It is not the only one, and I do not claim that it is the best. However, this would be the approach that I would use in such a case.

That is, I would go with object composition via interfaces (a bit sort of Strategy + Template patterns.)

```
// at package-level visibility

interface EnumHandler
{
  SomeRetVal doSomething(DBEnum dbEnum);
}

final class DefaultHandler implements EnumHandler
{
  static DefaultHandler _handler = new DefaultHandler();

  SomeRetVal doSomething(DBEnum dbEnum)
  {
      return ping;
  }
}

// at public visibility

public interface Actionable
{
   // meh, you might need such an interface, or maybe not, just added here
   // for illustration purposes. you'll have to make a decision if you need it
   // or not.
   SomeRetVal doSomething();
}

// have the enum implement the interface if you determine you need
// such an interface
public Enum DBEnum implements Actionable
{
   // ONE and THREE share the same logic. TWO has its own.

   ONE("db-key-one" ),
   TWO("db-key-two, new EnumHandler(){
             SomeRetVal doSomething(DBEnum dbEnum){ return pong; } } ),
   THREE("db-key-three");

   // this guy keeps track of enums by key
   static private java.util.Map<String,DBEnum> _MAP = 
     java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(
       new java.util.HashMap<String,DBEnum>() );

   final private String _key;
   final private EnumHandler _handler;

   // allows construction of customized handler
   DBEnum(final String key, final EnumHandler handler)
   {
      this._key = key;
      this._handler = handler;

      this._MAP.put(key, this)
   }

   // construct using default handler
   DBEnum(final String key)
   {
      this(key, DefaultHandler._handler);
   }  

   // have toString() return the key instead of this.name()
   public String toString()
   {
       return this._key;
   }

   // implementing Actionable interface (if you choose to use such an interface)
   public SomeRetVal doSomething()
   {
      return this._handler.doSomething(this);
   }

   // get enum by key
   public static DBEnum getByDbKey(final String key)
   {
     DBEnum retVal = this._MAP.get(key);
     if( retVal == null ){ throw new IllegalArgumentException("thingie not found");

     return retVal;
   }

   public static Iterator<String> dbKeys()
   {
     return _map.keySet().iterator();
   }
}

// somewhere else
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DBEnum.ONE.doSomething();

    DBEnum.geByDBKey( DBEnum.TWO.toString() ).doSomething();

    for( String dbKey : DBEnum.dbKeys() )
    {
        DBEnum.getByDbKey( dbKey ).doSomething();
    }

    // the following will kaput with an IllegalArgumentException
    DBEnum.getDbByKey( "key-that-is-not-there" ).doSomething();
}
```

---

One could, in theory, as far as pulling the actual db keys from a resource file when the Enum is loaded by the class loader. The contents (and changes to the content) of the resource file could be a deployment item. There can be significant advantages to this - a change to the db key would not require a recompilation. **BUT** such an approach will make things a bit more complex. It would be something I would implement **after** everything else is done right.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, as I don't need to attach different logic to different enum values, rather I'm trying to define a common interface (in the general sense, not the specific Java `interface` sense) that ensures a set of enum classes all provide certain methods, including some methods that ought to be static. However, your approach could define a public method that calls a static handler method in the implementation. An interesting answer nonetheless!

Comment: Ahhh, I see now what you are going after. Interesting challenge indeed as Java itself doesn't provide good means to do so. I bet something like this could be done in a snap with Ruby.